# View для DataTemplate

Tags: wpf

Добрый день!

Я использую ContentPresenter, который при нажатии на нужную кнопку отображает тот или иной DataTemplate.

В ресурсах описал два DataTemplate

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
        <Grid>
           ...
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
        <Grid>
           ...
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Т.к. планируется, что каждый DataTemplate будет громоздким, можно ли выделить его структуру в отдельный файл  XAML? То есть сделать отдельное View для DataTemplate.

Спасибо.

Comment: Создать `usercontrol` и пихать его в `DataTemplate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. Создайте `UserControl`ы под каждый `DataTemplate`. Не забудьте указать `DataType`:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionaty>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1" DataType="{x:Type VM1}">
         <view:UserControl1/>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="Template2" DataType="{x:Type VM2}">
         <view:UserControl2/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```